Computation of pullback along the canonical morphism $A\rightarrow A\otimes^{L}_{B}A$
Consider the derived tensor product $Z[T]/(T)\otimes_{Z[T]}^{L}Z[T]/(T)$ as the pushout 
And also we can shape the pullback of the diagram $Z[T]/(T)\rightarrow Z\otimes_{Z[T]}Z\leftarrow Z[T]/(T)$ as shown in the below diagram:

First of all, about the derived tensor product $Z\otimes_{Z[T]}Z$, I do know that the underlying chain complex has the following form $Z\oplus Z[1]$ as it has resolution $Z\stackrel{\cdot 0}\longrightarrow Z\rightarrow Z\otimes_{Z[T]}^{L}Z$ which is the $Z[T]\stackrel{\cdot T}\longrightarrow Z[T]\rightarrow Z[T]/(T)$ after $(-)\otimes_{Z[T]}^{L}Z[T]$.
But the $\textbf{'derived' ring structure}$ on this underlying chain complex seems to be unknown so I really don't know $\textbf{how to compute the pullback along $Z\rightarrow Z\otimes_{Z[T]}^{L}Z$}$, not to mention the more general case replacing $Z[T]$ witg $A$ and $Z[T]/(T)$ with $A/I$.
Or if it's indeed hard to compute the exact pullback ring, I am wondering if there is certain 'square zero' property of the map $Z\times_{Z\otimes_{Z[T]}^{L}Z}Z\rightarrow Z[T]/(T)=Z$? For example, can we show that the kernel $K$ of this map is square zero: $K^{2}=0$? Or connectivity conditions like $K\in Mod(Z[T])_{\geq 1,\leq 2}$?
